# Difference between checking MX and FILTER_VALIDATE_IP to validate domain

Tags: php, validation, if-statement, dns

these two PHP scripts validate a website domain and I just want to know what the difference is between the two. Do they both do the same thing? Is one better to use than the other?

This is the first one:

```
if(!filter_var(gethostbyname($website), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
//returns false
}
```

And this is the second one:

```
if (!checkdnsrr($website,"MX")) {
//returns false
}
```

They both seem to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well both functions are different in terms of operations i.e what they do.
 
**FILTER_VALIDATE_IP:**
 
It simply checks if the given data is in proper IPv4 or IPv6 format depending upon the flag you pass, check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php). 
**checkdnsrr:**
Its purpose is only fetching the live DNS records on the web for the corresponding IP OR host name given and not to validate IP address. Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php).

Check below code:

```
$website = 'www.apple.com';
echo 'GetHostName:'.gethostbyname($website).'<br>';
echo (!filter_var(gethostbyname($website), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))?'FALSE   by FILTER<br>':'TRUE by Filter<br>';
echo (!checkdnsrr($website,"MX"))?'FALSE by cDNS<br>':'TRUE By cDNS<Br>';


echo (!filter_var(gethostbyname('127.0.0.1'),   FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))?'FALSE by FILTER<br>':'TRUE by Filter<br>';
echo (!checkdnsrr('127.0.0.1',"MX"))?'FALSE by cDNS<br>':'TRUE By cDNS<Br>';
```

Output:

```
GetHostName:23.15.152.48
TRUE by Filter
TRUE By cDNS
TRUE by Filter
FALSE by cDNS
```

**Conclusion:**
To validate a domain you should use **checkdnsrr()** it will return false if no DNS records are found.

Comment: So for the purpose of validating a domain, which one would be more accurate?

Comment: To validate a domain you should use **checkdnsrr()** it will return false if no DNS records are found.